# Is it a good practice (feasible) to combine both nodeAfinity and podAffinity rules when assigning Pods to Nodes on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, affinity

Is it a good practice (feasible) to **combine both nodeAfinity and podAffinity rules** when assigning Pods to Nodes on kubernetes.

Example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: node-and-pod-affinity-combined
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
            operator: In
            values:
            - e2e-az1
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: node-label-key
            operator: In
            values:
            - some-node-label-value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can combine them. Actually this enforces a sort of affinity on scheduling of pods you have selected using `podAffinity`. Even if those pods do not have any nodeAffinity or podAffinity themselves, scheduler will try to schedule them to nodes on which your `node-and-pod-affinity-combined` pods are running.

More common use case would be using `nodeAffinity` and `podAntiAffinity` together to spread the pods on set of nodes.